# Twilio WebChat client - Create-React-App - Bundling and hashing

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I need to be able to re-bundle the Twilio webchat client .js file to be used by third parties.

I want to add custom react components to the web client and publish this version to my server for use on other websites.

The sample project based https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/installing-and-using-flex-webchat works fine however it chunks the outputted files and adds a hash and doesn't include the required Twilio-Flex components bundled.

Any assistance would be great.

Comment: Can you customize the chat component using the provided extensibility points?

Comment: I need to add custom React components.

Comment: Have you tried the npm route?